# How to delete charaters of word in vim?

Tags: vim

My cursor is on the `C`, and I want to delete the word `With`.

How to do it ?

```
[self showErrorFullScreenWithContent:content image:nil needRefresh:NO];
                             ^
```

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, `dFW` will suffice. This `d`eletes *to the previous, inclusively (`F`)* `W` character.

There's also [a plugin for camel case motions](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion) if you need something more comfortable and work in CamelCase a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it the way you like better. For example,

<kbd>4</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>left arrow</kbd>

Or press <kbd>d</kbd> and left-click mouse on "W" letter. Etc.